# Getting relative angular velocity from quaternions

Tags: python, computational-geometry, quaternions

I want to simulate gyroscope readings (angular velocity in local frame) by supplied vectors.
I have this vectors (x,y,z) with sampling 1s:

```
[0, 0, 1000]
[469.47156279, 0.0, 882.94759286]
[981.62718345, 0.0, 190.80899538]
```

Rotating Z by 28 degrees by Y axis and then by 51 degrees again around Y.
Vectors looks like this:
[image]

I am getting quaternions describing relative rotations using

```
scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.align_vectors
```

In a form that

```
1. vector_orientation = quaternion_1
2. vector_orientation = quaternion_2 * quaternion_1
3. vector_orientation = quaternion_3 * quaternion_2 * quaternion_1
```

I found this [How to compute angular velocity using numpy-quaternion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56790186/how-to-compute-angular-velocity-using-numpy-quaternion) question, so I tried to implement suggested code for calculating angular velocity between orientation 2 and 3:

```
# quaternion_3 is relative to quaternion_2, so I guess I don't need quaternion difference
delta_q = quaternion_3
delta_q_len = np.linalg.norm(delta_q[1:])
delta_q_angle = 2*np.arctan2(delta_q_len, delta_q[0])
w = delta_q[1:] * delta_q_angle * 1
```

I got some velocities - `[0.0, 0.38320564, 0.0]`.

However if I want to check the result by applying it to the quaternion_2 by obtaining derivative using this equation:
[image]

So in Python:

```
omega = np.array([[0, -w[0], -w[1], -w[2]], 
                  [w[0], 0, w[2], -w[1]], 
                  [w[1], -w[2], 0, w[0]], 
                  [w[2], w[1], -w[0], 0]])
quaternion_derivative = 0.5 * omega @ quaternion_2
```

And integrate it with

```
quaternion_result = (2 * quaternion_derivative / quaternion_2).normalized()
```

Problem is `quaternion_result != quaternion_3`. Does anybody has some idea what I am doing wrong?

Edit:
Adding (not)working example. Also changed angles for better demonstration. I am using https://github.com/moble/quaternion for work with quaternions:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
import quaternion as qt

def get_quaternion_rotation(v1, v2):
    rotation,_ = R.align_vectors([v1], [v2])
    qt = rotation.as_quat()
    return np.array([qt[3], qt[0], qt[1], qt[2]])

def rotate_vector(vector, axis, angle):
    # normalize
    unit_axis = axis/np.linalg.norm(axis)
    angle_radians = np.radians(angle)
    rotation_vector = angle_radians * unit_axis
    rotation = R.from_rotvec(rotation_vector)
    return rotation.apply(vector)

# 1. vector is just 1000 in Z
vector_1 = np.array([0, 0, 1000])
# 2. vector rotates vector_1 28 degrees by Y
vector_2 = rotate_vector(vector_1, [0,1,0], 28)
# 3. vector rotates vector_2 51 degrees by Y
vector_3 = rotate_vector(vector_2, [0,1,0], 51)

# rotations between vectors
quaternion_1 = get_quaternion_rotation([0,0,0], vector_1)
quaternion_2 = get_quaternion_rotation(vector_2, vector_1)
quaternion_3 = get_quaternion_rotation(vector_3, vector_2)

delta_q = quaternion_3
delta_q_len = np.linalg.norm(delta_q[1:])
delta_q_angle = 2 * np.arctan2(delta_q_len, delta_q[0])
w = delta_q[1:] * delta_q_angle * 1

omega = np.array([[0, -w[0], -w[1], -w[2]], 
                  [w[0], 0, w[2], -w[1]], 
                  [w[1], -w[2], 0, w[0]], 
                  [w[2], w[1], -w[0], 0]])


qt_derivative = 0.5 * omega @ quaternion_2
# converting to quaternion type for normalizing
qt_derivative = qt.quaternion(qt_derivative[0], qt_derivative[1], qt_derivative[2], qt_derivative[3]).normalized()
# apply derivative to quaternion_2
qt_result = (2 * qt_derivative / qt.quaternion(quaternion_2[0], quaternion_2[1], quaternion_2[2], quaternion_2[3])).normalized()

print(f"Quaternion 3 = {quaternion_3}")
print(f"Quaternion result = {qt.as_float_array(qt_result)}")


rotation_quaternion_3 = R.from_quat([quaternion_3[1], quaternion_3[2], quaternion_3[3], quaternion_3[0]])
print(f"Applied rotation from quaternion_3 to vector_2: {rotation_quaternion_3.apply(vector_2)}")
rotation_result = R.from_quat([qt_result.x, qt_result.y, qt_result.z, qt_result.w])
print(f"Applied rotation from quaternion result to vector_2: {rotation_result.apply(vector_2)}")
```

Result is:

```
Quaternion 3 = [0.90258528 0.         0.4305111  0.        ]
Quaternion result = [-2.77555756e-17 -2.76809689e-17 -1.00000000e+00 -1.11022302e-16]
Applied rotation from quaternion_3 to vector_2: [981.62718345   0.         190.80899538]
Applied rotation from quaternion result to vector_2: [-4.69471563e+02  2.22044605e-13 -8.82947593e+02]
```

Comment: can you provide computed values for `quaternion_result` and `quanternion_2`?

Comment: You may want to extend your question with a full Python script which prints `quaternion_result` and `quaternion_2`, and then does an `assert quaternion_result = quaternion_2`. This would make it easier for your others to help.

Comment: It is most likely these two values are differents because of float imprecision

Comment: I added whole script. I found out that sometimes is kind of working, but sometimes it fails big time (like in the posted example).